# Convergence sup norm on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

How to show the following:

When $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ uniformly in $[0,1]$ where $f_{n}$ and $f$ are continuously differentiable
THEN

derivative of $f_{n}$ converges to derivative of $f$ uniformly as well.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)= \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $f=0$.